# C++ OpenGL functions not found

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, mingw, glut

## OpenGL functions not found

I installed `GLEW`, `GLUT` and `GLFW` for MinGW on Windows.
Put all of the header files into `C:\MinGW\include\GL` and `C:\MinGW\incude\GLFW`. Copied the `glew32.dll`,`glfw3.dll` and `freeglut.dll` binaries to a folder where i had this script:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
glutInit(&argc, args);
glutCreateWindow("GLEW Test");

GLenum err = glewInit();

if (GLEW_OK != err)
{
  cout << "Error:\n" << err;

}
cout << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION);
}
```

I compiled it using `g++ glewtest.cpp -o glewtest -lfreeglut -lglew32 -lglfw3` and when i ran it a window named "GLEW Test" popped up for a second and the version of glew "2.1.0" was printed in the terminal.

Then i wanted to add some content to the window and i found a example script on the web to do that:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void renderScene(void) {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.5,0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0.0);
    glEnd();

        glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // init GLUT and create Window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(320,320);
    glutCreateWindow("Lighthouse3D - GLUT Tutorial");

    // register callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);

    // enter GLUT event processing cycle
    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

But when compiling it this time using the same command i just got a lot of errors like:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mmm\AppData\Local\Temp\cckUUJHk.o:glewtest.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `glClear@4'
```

I didn't find any helpful resources and no matter what i did it always failed to compile.
Did somebody else ever encounter such an issue too? How can i resolve this?

Comment: Why isn't your second program `#include`ing `GL/glew.h`?

Comment: I would expect the compile/link command to have `-lGL` at the end, no?

Comment: When i added glew the compiler freaked out: `c:\mingw\include\gl\glew.h:14338:73: error: 'GLuint64' does not name a type; did you mean 'GLuint'?
 typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLDRAWCOMMANDSSTATESADDRESSNVPROC) (const GLuint64* indirects, const GLsizei* sizes, const GLuint* states, const GLuint* fbos, GLuint count);`

Comment: @G.M. It's `-lOpenGL32` for Windows, probably together with `-lGdi32`.

Comment: @flyx yep adding the -lOpenGL32 flag fixed it